# How to use constants and formatted strings on annotations ErrorMessages (C# MVC 4)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, annotations

Well, at this point i'm just trying to optimize my code for possible future maintenance, and as so, on entities definitions I'm trying to centralize string size for properties (and other annotations) on one single point.

Here's an Example:

```
    // ---=== CONSTS ===---
    protected const int Nome_MaxLength = 120;
    protected const int Sigla_MaxLength = 4;

    public int IDTipoServico { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Tipo Serviço")]
    [StringLength(Nome_MaxLength, ErrorMessage = String.Format("O nome de um tipo de serviço deve conter no máximo {0} caracteres", Nome_MaxLength))]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Sigla Tipo Serviço")]
    [StringLength(Sigla_MaxLength, ErrorMessage = String.Format("A sigla de um tipo serviço deve conter no máximo {0} caracteres", Sigla_MaxLength))]
    public string Sigla { get; set; }
```

Even though it seems simple and straightforward, it wont work... Compiler is giving me "An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type" error.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've seen this implemented via wrapper classes around the default attributes. That's an option for you (can't think of anything else right now).

Comment: That would do... Can you post an example (as i'm not being able to correctly do it). But i do think this is the way...

Comment: If you're open to using a library, http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com might give you a bit more flexibility that writing your own attributes.